# C++ map with a struct

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct

So, I got this:

```
struct People_Info {
  bool isWorking;
  std::string name;
  int age;
  float height;
};
int counter = 0;
int random = urand(1, 4);
std::map<uin64, People_Info> PeopleMap;
```

Now, a function will get called that will create an entry in the map with this struct that will set some default values:

```
PeopleMap[counter].isWorking = false;
PeopleMap[counter].name = "Mr";
PeopleMap[counter].age = 1;
PeopleMap[counter].height = 1.60f;
counter++;
```

Now, that is the function that should make an entry for someone new, but, throughout the script I will remove some entries, so if I got 5 elements, and I remove e.g. the second one, then, I want to edit some variables of everyone in the map:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
  if(PeopleMap[i] == PeopleMap.end())  // Don't edit map entries that are erased
    continue;

  PeopleMap[i].isWorking = true;
}
```

Now, for some reason it is still editing all the entries, do I need to use new to make a struct for every entry?

Comment: Is `if(PeopleMap[i] == PeopleMap.end())` part of your actual code? Because that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PeopleMap.end()` doesn't return a valid argument, it's like a ghost node.

For example, a way to iterate in map could be:

```
for(std::map<uin64, People_Info>::iterator it = PeopleMap.begin();it != PeopleMap.end() ;it++)
```

See, `PeobleMap` is like a ghost node in the end denotes that you have reach the end.
In the previous `for`, if you like to access to map values you could do:

```
it->first // uint64
it->second.isWorking
```

So, if you use iterators you don't have to check erased values and you would be able to edit a parameter in each pair in the map (less key)

Answer (score 2):

When using the subscript operator to access a key in the map that doesn't exist, yet, a corresponding element is inserted. It is immaterial that the object was erased before: it will still be inserted if it doesn't exist.

To access all elements in a map you don't use the keys but rather you 'd use iterators over the map. This way no new elements get inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The following is incorrect:

```
if(PeopleMap[i] == PeopleMap.end())
```

You probably meant to say

```
if(PeopleMap.find(i) == PeopleMap.end())
```